# Changing the arrangement order of objects programmatically on view controller

Tags: objective-c, ios6

I need to be able to change the order (arrangement) of the objects on my UIViewController such that when one thing is clicked it comes to the front, when another is clicked it comes to the front etc. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure. On the parent, call the UIView method bringSubviewToFront:.  There's also exchangeSubviewAtIndex:withSubviewAtIndex: for more complex re-orderings.

Comment: Sorry - I am not sure what you mean. When I write UIView there is no bringSubViewToFront method.

Comment: @RichardGriffiths The method is `bringSubviewToFront:` and you need to call it on a variable of type `UIView` since it is an instance variable.

Comment: Ok - got it thanks.  [self.view bringSubviewToFront:control];

Comment: It's too late to edit my previous comment - I meant to say instance method, not instance variable.